# ssh client ignores identity settings on config file

Tags: ssh

Here my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# Identity for github work account
  Host github-work
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-work
  IdentitiesOnly yes

# Identity for gitlab personal account
  Host gitlab-personal
  HostName gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I've tested connection using:

```bash
$ ssh -T git@github.com
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've test using explicit identity file:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/github-work -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jcabre/.ssh/github-work':
Hi husresfrai! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I've tried to get some details using `-v`:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com | xclip -selection clipboard
OpenSSH_9.6p1, OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/jcabre/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-8405f9f3
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-8405f9f3
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/jcabre/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/jcabre/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/jcabre/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:YptwdVrGGcdZbjnhFoKAfYHOb/lXh6OLwKkC2+BLaFA
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:YptwdVrGGcdZbjnhFoKAfYHOb/lXh6OLwKkC2+BLaFA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jcabre/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

As you can see, `ssh` client doesn't use my configured key on `~/.ssh/config` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: When this happens to me, it's usually because I have an ssh-agent process running and it hasn't loaded my new private key.

Comment: IIRC ssh_config matches on the `Host` keyword - so if you want it to apply the `github-work` identity you need to explicitly invoke it as such e.g. `ssh -T github-work` I think?